# Oracle Database installation on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, installation

I am new to ubuntu and oracle, and I couldn't install oracle 18c on ubuntu! If anyone can help me with a clear solution for a newbie!! Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2OVX.png)

Comment: Please post the errors you get

Comment: @nissimabehcera I edited the post and added the error I got! thank you

Comment: Try to install libaio1 software by this command: sudo apt-get install libaio1

Comment: Already installed! I don't know what should I do and I don't understand this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle is not designed to run on Ubuntu.  There are a few different branches of the Linux family tree, and ubuntu is an entireley different branch than the one oracle was designed for.  You will find hacks on the interntet to get it installed, but that's all they are - hacks. And if you do get it installed there is never any assurance that everything will work as it should.

The ususal approach for running oracle on an Ubuntu machine is to install Oracle Virtual Box, using that to create a VM that runs a certified OS, like Oracle Linux.  Then install your oracle db on that.

I have a few blog articles on it, [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/personal-test-systems/).

Comment: What I want is to migrate from oracledb to Hive and in order to do that I want to install oracle and migrate a data sample before moving to the real data! If you have any tips! I would really appreciate it! thank you!

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about Hive, nor your migration method, nor your testing methods. I don't know anything about what resources you have available, other than an Ubuntu machine which I would suppose is your personal computer.

Comment: No worries! Thank you for your help anyways :)

Comment: Speaking from personal experience, Hive is _not_ a replacement for Oracle in any way shape or form. Unless you have some very specific use cases for large analytical queries, Oracle will outperform it every time. It is most certainly not designed with transaction support in mind; most table formats aren't even ACID-compliant. Be very careful with your expectations on what you will be able to use Hive for.

Comment: It's for a big data analytics project and the company asked me to migrate to hadoop and hive!

Comment: Then trying to install oracle on Ubuntu is an x-y question.  Your "migration" shouldn't be destructive to your source oracle database, so why not just go with the migration directly?  It will be much simpler than trying to put up a test oracle database on an Ubuntu machine, and if something goes wrong, just delete the data from the Hive db and start over.

Comment: That's what I'm gonna do ! I want to use a sample data to learn how to migrate from oracle to hive! and the original data I don't have access to it yet :p

Comment: Well, installing Oracle on a VM on your personal pc might work, but it will present some challenges that would not exist on "real" servers.  On the other hand, meeting and overcoming those challenges will be a good learning experience, on a lot of different fronts.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hack with docker to use Oracle database on Ubuntu. Simply download/pull the container available at

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe
```

Then run it as

```
docker container run -d -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_PASSWORD=oracle  --name oracle21 gvenzl/oracle-xe
```

and then connect to it from Ubuntu via some SQL editor e.g., Oracle SQL developer.